# Load event handler code not executing when showing a form

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub HangmanEnterWord_Load(ByVal sender
    As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Handles MyBase.Load

    Label1.Text = GameStage
    If GameStage = 1 Then
        lblPlayerNumber.Text = 1
    End If
    If GameStage = 2 Then
        lblPlayerNumber.Text = 2
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the load event handler code for a form that I reopen during my application using:

```
HangmanEnterWord.Show()
```

The load event handler code executes when the form first opens however when the form is closed and re-opened, the load event code does not execute. How can I go about getting this to work?

Comment: is your machine 64 bit?

Comment: yes it is, does that make a difference?

Comment: how do you "close" the form?  The form load event only fires the first time a form is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine 64bit then
add in `Main()`

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)
```

Reason behind is that there was an unhandled NullReferenceException thrown and this exception was somehow "muted".
If you debug using F11, you will find it.

Comment: where exactly do I add Main()?

Comment: I added Main() into the module with that line of code however I still get  NullReferenceException unhandled